# FileNotFoundException when downloading an image from a firebase server to android internal storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, filenotfoundexception

I keep on stumbling on FileNotFoundException even though everything seems to work fine, the file exists in the specified link and the connection is good.

Here is my snippet to download an image from the firebase server.

```
   btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String imageUrl= imageUri[0];
       // System.out.println("The Magazine Uri is: " + imageUri[0]);

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                    // Creating a reference to the link
                    StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl);
                    // Getting the Download url and conveting it to java.url
                    URL url = new URL(httpsReference.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.connect();



                    File file;
                    file=new File(mContext.getFilesDir(),"DownloadedImage.png");
                    OutputStream fileOutPut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    //FileOutputStream fileOutPut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                    System.out.println("TotalSize :" + totalSize);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                    int bufferLength = 0;
                    while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        fileOutPut.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        int downloadedSize = 0;
                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                        System.out.println("Downloaded Size :" + downloadedSize);
                    }
                    fileOutPut.close();
                } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error : IOException " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
                }
            }
        }).start();


    }
});
```

below is the error log:

> 08-07 14:16:29.280 1366-1386/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 6153393 , only wrote 6153120
>   08-07 14:16:32.505 1366-1387/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 6460704 , only wrote 6307920
>   08-07 14:16:40.573 3381-3545/? I/System.out: Error : IOException java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsoutmain.appspot.com/o/februaryissue.png?alt=media&token=87602fe6-d7af-4ab4-b41e-59be7fb3deb1
>   08-07 14:16:40.573 3381-3545/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsoutmain.appspot.com/o/februaryissue.png?alt=media&token=87602fe6-d7af-4ab4-b41e-59be7fb3deb1
>   08-07 14:16:40.573 3381-3545/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
>   08-07 14:16:40.573 3381-3545/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>   08-07 14:16:40.573 3381-3545/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>   08-07 14:16:40.573 3381-3545/? W/System.err:     at yenettaapp.whatsoutmain.DownloadPop$1$1$1.run(DownloadPop.java:108)
>   08-07 14:16:40.573 3381-3545/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

What seems to be the problem? What are the possible ways to go around this?

Comment: Your code breaks with HTTP 403 error which states its forbidden to access the URL

Comment: But I can access the URL from other browsers?

Comment: Yes but since the file is in Firebase i guess you will have to set the correct Storage reference before downloading it.

Comment: Okay, one moment...

Comment: Refer to this link - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Comment: Now I'm getting this...Error : MalformedURLException java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh@85f49c4
08     I made a change on the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading a file from Firebase Storage reference has to be done using a different method . Use below code -

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
// Creating a reference to the link
StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl);

File file = null;

try {
    file=new File(mContext.getFilesDir(),"DownloadedImage.png");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


httpsReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

        System.out.println("kudos");
        // Local temp file has been created
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by local temp file has been created??!

Comment: I mean that image would then be downloaded and save at the location where we mentioned the file. So in your case on success the image will  be in DownloadedImage.png

Comment: islandRef is not our storage reference, it's httpsReference if i'm not mistaken?!!

Comment: Yes sorry my bad. Updated it

Comment: Is this the efficient way ?! What if I want to download 2 or more files??!

Comment: Your question talked about only 1 file and hence the answer. This is the standard way that Firebase approves. Now to download multiple files, depend on your scenario. If its in a List, I would suggest you use Glide library or Picasso. If its not in a list and you need to pre-download and cache it, then you can iterate through the various files this way.

Comment: @NathanDamtew If this solved your problem, please accept the answer :)

Comment: I didn't get the chance to try it. Sorry. Thanks for the tip tho.